# Plotting Confidence Interval Width against sample size for Bootstrapped Data

Tags: r

I have bootstrapped an n=30 sample to n=1000.
I would like to plot the Confidence Interval Width against sample size, to be able to graphically represent the sample size that would be required for x% confidence interval. I.e. Confidence interval width when n=10, n=20 n=30 ... n=1000. Expecting it to reach an asymptote at some point before 1000.
How would I do this?

I tried this, copying it from a previous post, and inputting my data instead.

```
set.seed(144)
ci.widths <- sapply(seq(10, 100, 5), function(x) mean(replicate(1000, {
  r <- sample(nrow(baseRan), x, replace=TRUE)
  diff(cor.test(baseRan$Ranpopsize[r], baseRan$Ranpopsize[r])$conf.int)
})))

plot(seq(10, 100, 5), ci.widths, xlab="Sample size", ylab="CI width")
```

and I received a plot, however the CI widths were between 4.0e^-17 and 1.6e^-17 so I am unsure what has gone wrong as this is not expected.

My data set including the 1000 bootstrapped population estimates is in (baseRan).
Ranpopsize is the variable containing the 1000 population estimates.
Thank you :)

Comment: I fear this is statistical delusional thinking. There is no valid method that lets you bootstrap a small sample size and lets you narrow the CI to the same precision as you would have achieved with a sample size 1000.

Comment: Thank you, I am essentially trying to graph how the confidence interval width changes with sample size, like in the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4cXC.png which was produced with the same code under a different data set. As I have bootstrapped the data, I essentially have 1000 different samples. If I randomly select 2, I will likely have a high CI width. Randomly selected 10, a high but smaller CI. Randomly select 100, I should have an even smaller CI width. This is what I am trying to show graphically, like in the image I linked. Is this possible?

Comment: I’m sure something of that sort is possible. However I do not think the process has been clearly described. Do you imagine that you have 1000 observations and you want to do bootstrapping on varying sizes of samples? Do you further imagine that you will be comparing such result to the results you would be getting if you had been doing finite sample calculations in a classical statistical context? Throwing the further request for minimum sample size complicates the problem. It’s still unclear what is the goal.